# How to fix crash issue on a recycler view due to JsonSyntaxException?

Tags: android, json, crash

How to fix crash issue on a recycler view due to JsonSyntaxException?

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException:Expected an int but was 0.5 at line 1 column 39043 path $.items[10].weight
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Step-1: Please try to crosscheck your json with your model class

Step-2: If any data type mismatch found, fix it.

*Say for an example, if you define your 'weight' as an 'Int' on your model class and your json data type is 'double' then update your model class accordingly.*

Step-3: Rebuild your project and run after cleanup.